# Changing DHCP range makes me lose internet access

Tags: networking, dhcp, internet

Hy,

I'm trying to increase my network ip address from:

```
IP DHCPIpv4: 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.250
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Server: 192.168.1.254
Gateway: 192.168.1.254
```

To

```
IP DHCPIpv4: 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.3.250
Mask: 255.255.252.0
Server: 192.168.1.254
Gateway: 192.168.1.254
```

But, when I change it, it loses internet connection.
All the devices connected to the router, are still available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Server" is the DNS resolver ? Can you ping it ? Try to "tracert" to an IP on Internet

Comment: The devices configured through `DHCP` will use the new `/22` network, but the router is configured statically, so probably it still thinks it is a `/24` network.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz , there is really an option on Interface -> LocalNetwork -> IP Address List:

IP Address/IPv4 Mask   <=> Type
10.0.0.138/24     <=> Static
192.168.1.254/24 <=> Static
192.168.1.253   <=> Shared content

so I should change de 192.168.1.254/24 to 192.168.1.254/22
I will give feedback after my test.

Comment: That really solved my problem. After this changes, it started working :)